ReactJS object map not re-rendering after filter
I've got a ReactJS project with ThreeJS elements. I'm simply trying to make the ProjectCards refresh after selecting the ServicesCard. Right now it works, but once filtering, the list of projects will never go back up in quantity.
EX: If I filter the list to a service with 2 projects, it will show 2 results properly. If I then filter to another service with 1 result, it will display properly. If I filter back to the service with 2 results, I will only get 1 result. The console output of the map is always correct, but it does not present correctly.
I've attempted various ways to re-render, but haven't had any luck getting it to work. I initially had the filter & map as one line, but separated for debug.
const ServicesCard = ({ index, title, category, icon, onSelect }) => (
      <Tilt className='xs:w-[250px] w-full'>
          <div
            onClick={() => onSelect(category)}
            options={{
              max: 45,
              scale: 1,
              speed: 450,
            }}
            className='bg-primary bg-opacity-80 hover:bg-opacity-30 rounded-[20px] py-5 px-12 min-h-[280px] flex justify-evenly items-center flex-col'
          >
          </div>
      </Tilt>
);
    
const Services = () => {
          const [search, setSearch] = useState("all");
          const ref = useRef()
        
          const filterProjects = projects.filter((project) => {
            if (search == "all") {
              return project.categories
            }
              return project.categories == search
          })
        
          return (
            <>
              <div className='mt-20 flex flex-wrap justify-around gap-10'>
                {servicesList.map((service, index) => (
                  <ServicesCard key={servicesList.title} index={index} {...service} onSelect={setSearch} />
                ))}
              </div>
              <div className='mt-20 flex flex-wrap gap-7'>
                {filteredProjects.map((project, index) => (
                  <ProjectCard key={project.index} index={project} {...project} />
                ))}
              </div>
            </>
          );
};
export default SectionWrapper(Services, "services");
    
 const projects = [
  {
    name: "Project 1",
    categories: "category1",
  },
   {
    name: "Project 2",
    categories: "category2",
  },
   {
    name: "Project 3",
    categories: "category2",
  },
];


What is projects that is being filtered? I don't see any other "reducing" action in the code you've shared. Can you [edit] to add clarifying and any additional debugging details and to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

@DrewReese I've added the Projects and reduced some fluff from the code. I'm filtering the Projects list by "search", which is triggered by the onClick of the ServicesCard (set values, ex: "category1". The filteredProjects is being re-ran in the Return, but isn't updating the ProjectCard map properly. On initial load, all projects are displayed (the array is unfiltered).

I think you have some minor issues with some of the props, but otherwise your base logic appears to work as expected. Here's a demo Codesandbox. Feel free to fork the sandbox and add more of your actual code to see if you can reproduce the issue there, and if so, share a link back so we can inspect it live.

@DrewReese thank you for your help! This sandbox is showing what I am seeing on my end when i do a console log. It's the actual rendering that isn't loading.
I created a thinned down project and uploaded to sandbox. This is working locally but throwing a "cannot find vite" error that I'm unable to resolve.
https://codesandbox.io/p/github/rtnlsltn/test/draft/friendly-flower

@DrewReese sorry first time actually sharing something on codesandbox. I added you to the team and also this link should work: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/rtnlsltn/test/test/test

@DrewReese Great! Click Full Stack, then any other, then back to Full Stack. You'll originally get 2 results, then it will only display 1. Anytime the quantity of results is reduced, it will not go back up.

I've been able to narrow it down to the motion.div in the ProjectCard component, if it's commented out then the filteredProjects array properly gets all the mapped elements rendered. It's like Framer Motion is holing on to the face that a specific div was already animated. I've noticed some other odd animation issues with the service cards as well. Unfortunately I'm not experienced much in Framer Motion. I've re-tagged to include [tag:framer-motion] to maybe attract better attention.

@DrewReese I'm embarrassed I didn't try that first! I've checked the git issues and haven't found a similar report yet. Also posted in their discord with no response in a few days. Think I'm just going to try an alternative framework. Thank you for your help!
